# Описание знака "Электорат"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот описание знака `электорат`: "*Голосовать по 600 вопросам, минимум 25% от общего числа голосов относятся к вопросам*". Как видите, здесь повторяется слово "вопросам", из-за этого описание не очень понятное и звучит несогласованно. Предлагаю его немного изменить.

Comment: Я вообще ни в каком виде не понимаю, что там написано xD

Comment: Кстати, а если, в итоге, после получения знака, соотношение станет меньше, чем 1 к четырём, знак отберут?

Answer (score 7):

UPD

```
Голосовать по 600 вопросам и потратить на вопросы не менее 25% всех голосов.
```

1. Связал условия союзом "и", чтобы стало понятнее.
2. Поменял окончание у второго упоминания вопросов, чтобы они не путались в голове.
3. Заменил "отдать" на "потратить", потому что лучше отражает суть дела.

---

```
Проголосовать по 600 вопросам. Отдать вопросам не менее 25% всех голосов.
```

Знак требует выполнить два условия. Чтобы это подчеркнуть, предлагаю каждому условию дать отдельное предложение и каждое предложение начать глаголом.

Comment: Для случайного юзера не оч понятно как эти предложения связаны, через "и" или через "или".

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Спасибо, согласен. Обновил ответ. Как теперь?

Comment: так мне больше нравится, спасибо)

Comment: Соглашусь с вашим вариантом. Такое описание понятно.

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
25% или более голосов к сообщениям отданы вопросам, но не менее 600.
```

---

### Механику ж менять явно не будут

А текущее описание механики **совершенно правильное**. Но, возможно, не слишком удачно сформулировано. Оно *достаточно точно*, просто звучит не вполне естественно.

См. оригинал (достал с en.SO):

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

600 голосов нужно оставить **именно к вопросам**. Голоса за ответы этот счётчик не считает.

Во втором же показателе за 100% берутся **все** голоса (как за вопросы, так и за ответы), и 25% или более из них должно быть к вопросам.

Взгляните на скриншоты из моего профиля и сравните числа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Такие дела.*

Comment: Тогда уж "25% или более голосов к сообщениям (но не менее 600) отданы вопросам."

Comment: @Akina неплохо. Предложите ответом.

Answer (score 3):

Как вам такой вариант?

> Отдать не менее 25% своих голосов за 600 вопросов.

Мне кажется, довольно лаконично, но можно ещё убрать "своих".

Comment: "За" можно неверно истолковать, что это "только плюсы", но структурно просто отлично.

Comment: @D-side можно "за" убрать. Будет "600 вопросам".

Comment: Чтобы исключить "за", можно переформулировать так: `Потратить не менее 25% своих голосов на 600 вопросов.`

Answer (score 2):

```
Голосовать по 600 сообщениям, минимум 25% от общего числа голосов относятся к вопросам
```

В поддержку этой версии скажу, что в [других](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) [знаках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) уже упоминается `сообщение` как вопрос либо ответ.

Comment: Логично: если хотя бы 25% голосов к вопросам, значит могут быть и к ответам.

Comment: Считают именно 600 вопросов, а не 600 сообщений. Проверял на себе.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky точно, вы правы! А я уже и забыл, за что этот знак давался. Давно получил на обоих сайтах ))

Answer (score 1):

> 25% или более голосов к сообщениям (но не менее 600) отданы вопросам.